# How can I remove a file whose filename has weird characters?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
[root@host dir1]# ls -lrt
total 412
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13747 Jun  3 16:01 -lang?[5~?[5~?[5~?[5~?:q!
```

We tried different ways and they don't work.

```
[root@host dir1]#  ls -lrt | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I file rm file
rm: invalid option -- 'l'
Try `rm ./'-langq!'' to remove the file `-lang\033[5~\033[5~\033[5~\033[5~\033:q!'.
Try `rm --help' for more information.

[root@host dir1]# rm ./'-langq!''
> ^C
```

Comment: Try rm -rf ./-* ..... IF this is the only one beginning with a -

Comment: Hi Folks, using inum option helps.

Comment: You have two independent problems here: (1) the file name begins with `-`; and (2) the name contains unprintable characters. (1) is easily solved by including `./` before the name, or by using `rm -- ` to signify that the next parameter is not an option. To  answer (2), if your `ls` supports it, `ls -b` will show you the full file name with the unprintables expanded into escape sequences. If you can't specify the file name uniquely by using wild cards `*` and `?` (eg `rm -- -lang*:q!`) your best bet is to use a GUI file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file with weird characters and deleted it with this:

```
rm *lang*
```

wildcards make life easier for everyone. I entered these 2 sentences because of the character requirements.

Comment: That won't work if the file name begins with `-`: you would need `rm -- *lang*`.